# Exchange the order of limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

This is a problem I met when doing the homework, consider a positive sequence $\{a_{ij}\}$, if for each $i$, $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ exists and $\leq1$, for each $j$, $\lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}a_{ij}$ exists and $\leq1$, then, do we have
$$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}a_{ij}$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\{a_{ij}\}$ be defined by 1's across the diagonal and zero everywhere else:*

$$a_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $i = j$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases} $$

Then this sequence satisfies your hypotheses, but the limits are not equal. In fact,
$$\lim_{i \to \infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij} = 
\lim_{i \to \infty} 1 = 1.$$

However,
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\lim_{i\to\infty}a_{ij} =
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}0 = 0.
$$

*Of course, I'm interpreting "positive" as "non-negative". It isn't hard to make a strictly positive sequence. Let the indices $i$, and $j$ each start at 1. The following more complicated sequence works:

$$a_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
1 - 1/2^{i}, & \text{if $i = j$} \\
1/2^{i+j}, & \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [limit of the sum is the sum of the limits](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/94), provided each limit exists.

As Peter Tamaroff correctly states, the linked proof is not sufficient to assume you can, in fact, switch the sum and limit, but you can easily extend the method of the proof to infinite series.

Comment: Here you have infinite sums, Tim. Not the same.

Comment: It still holds, though, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. One needs certain hypothesis.

Comment: In this case it's either yes or no.  I would think the limit proof could be extended to an infinite series, unless you have a counterexample.

Comment: Well, true, but you cannot use the theorem you're citing. Using the hypotheses in the post, try to prove it. That is legitimate.

Comment: Pedro is correct -- the proof in the case of infinite series is not completely straightforward.  In general the result required is a variation of the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Sorry, it was late and I wanted to get this thread over with. @AntonioVargas please post that as an answer.